# all dash warning lights came on, barely driving

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, maintenance, warning-light

My vehicle is a 2009 Chevy Equinox. My engine was knocking a couple weeks back and flashed on every warning light i had. Doors stared locking and unlocking on their own and the shifter button was clicking as well. All my gauges on the dash were bouncing up and down. 
I got the engine replaced and on the way home it was driving okay. But today all the warning lights came on AGAIN! my car barely made it home. it is not dying, but seems like it wants to. when stopped, it takes a good bit for it to get going again with rough acceleration. when i had it tested at oreillys, nothing registered on their tester.
we replaced the alternator about 6 months ago
Lights on are ABS, Stablilark, BRAKE, check engine, check airbag, service vehicle soon

Comment: Check your charging system, the alternator may be failing.

Comment: Could be the charging system, but I bet the battery has a low charge, which could be caused from a faulty charging system or a bad battery. If the battery is over five years old, plan on changing it as it's seen its useful life.

Comment: I agree with @paulster2. The first step is to have battery checked. It is best to fully charge the battery off the vehicle is best. Then have the battery tested at a parts store. Replace if necessary. When you have a good battery in the vehicle immediately have the charging system checked. When all is good with battery and charging system, I suspect the problem is fixed. But even if it's not this is the first step to finding your problem.